# using from workspace block in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

how to use the "from workspace block in simulink" ?

I have tried using the from workspace block by given 10*2 matrix as input. it is appending some extra data along the data I have given .

and I have such 3 such blocks and want to know how I merge them.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html). Simulink is time-based so the data in your From Workspace block must be as a function of time. Does your 10 x 2 matrix represent a signal as a function of time? If so, it needs to be as follows:

> A two-dimensional matrix:
>
> - The first element of each matrix row is a
>     time stamp.
> - The rest of each row is a scalar or vector of signal
>     values.
>
> The leftmost element of each row is the time stamp of the
>   value(s) in the rest of the row.

10 values isn't very much, it's likely that Simulink will need additional data points at intermediate times, if you have the `Interpolate Data` check box ticked. If not, "the current output equals the output at the most recent time for which data exists".

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misunderstanding of the variables intended to be read by the FromWorkspace block.

The block expects a time series defining the value at various points in the simulation.

The From Workspace block help should point you in the right direction on this. Mathworks Help Documentation

I believe that something like the following would work for you:

```
>> WorkspaceVar.time=0;
>> WorkspaceVar.signals.values=zeros(10,2)
>> WorkspaceVar.signals.dimensions = [10,2]
```